# Avoid Code Tempring in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, security

What are the different ways available so that We avoid code tempring in ios. Please suggest any good way that we can check at server level to avoid code tempring not in source code. And how we can check that server call from app is from authorize app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS apps are most secured itself. It can not be tempered easily. While building your app no code file and XIB's kept as it is.

You can check it in these steps:

1. Right click on `.ipa` file and select `Open With` and then `Archive Utility`
2. Then it will create folder named `Payload` with `.app` file in it.
3. Now Right Click on .app file and select `Show Package Contents`

This will show you one folder with multiple files in it. Now try to open each file and read it. It will be in encrypted way.

For reference read this [link](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/security-hardening-ios-apps-abhinav-kumar)

Comment: In particular the code is encrypted with Apple's key.